# Create a regular expression with a series of "else" parameters

Tags: regex, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to create a regular expression that matches a word if it finds it. If it doesn't find the word I want it to try to match a second word. I want to repeat the process for a third and fourth word.

I need an "else" instruction. I tried `(?(?=regex)then|else)` which I found at http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html but was unsuccessful. I wrote it as `(?(?=1080)1080|720)` but it's not even recognized as a valid expression.

Note: I'm downloading video from a website and I want to download the highest quality video available. I'm using the Firefox Add-on DownThemAll which allows users to create custom filters using regular expressions. Specifically I want an expression that matches the word `1080`, if it doesn't find it try to match `720`, if it doesn't find it try to match `540`, if it doesn't find it try to match `480p/download`.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
1080|720|540|480p/download
```

The engine will try to match the left most pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the regex engine used by DownThemAll (probably JavaScript) does not support this feature (as you can see in the article you linked, only Perl, PCRE and .NET do).

However, in most engines, [alternatives](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) should be attempted from left to right. So this should do:

```
(1080|720|540|480)p/download
```